# How do I tell what is making an iterative search slow down?

Tags: ruby, search, iteration

I have an [iterative search algorithm on gist](https://gist.github.com/3300144) -- [(or see the full github repo here)](https://github.com/andrewcsmith/HD) -- that slows down after a few tens of thousands of iterations.

Summary:

- Searches for the optimal point from every adjacent point
- Picks that point as the new point
- If the point is a dead end (i.e., every adjacent point is further from the desired result) then it adds the point to a Hash of "banned points" to never use again
- The algorithm deletes the most recent point, and moves back to point n - 1

What would be the best way to tell when and how these iterations are slowing down? I'm thinking of something akin to a "lap-time" benchmark, that would let me graph which parts of my code are increasing in cost.

Switching from `Array#include?` to `Hash#has_key?` already sped the whole thing up by many orders of magnitude. But as the list of banned points gets longer and longer, would `Hash#has_key?` begin to lag up? What's the point at which I can expect to see significant slowing?

The banned_points `Hash` is just made up of `{"string rep. of array" => 1}`, because I'm only using it to search for the key.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check out ruby-prof (http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) to profile your code. Investigating performance issues without a profiling tool is a waste of time.

Comment: hash lookups should never lag (to my limited knowledge)